# Let G be a group and $g,h \in G$ such that $gh=hg$

Tags: group-theory

Assume $o(g)=m$ and $o(h)=n$ where $gcd(m,n)=1$. Prove $o(gh)=mn$.

I've started by trying to work backwards from $o(gh)=mn$ just to see whats going on and I don't think I'm on the right path really. I have that

$(gh)^{mn}=1$ and since they commute then we have $g^{mn}h^{mn}=(g^{m)^n}=(h^{n)^m}=1^n1^m$

I feel like I'm missing some kind of trick because I'm not sure how to use the gcd fact.

Comment: If $k^l = 1$ that doesn't mean that $o(k) = l$.  It means $o(k) \le l$.  Example.  $Z_8$  $4^4 = 1$ but $o(4) =2$ not $4$.  In $Z_{24}$, $o(12) = 2$ and $o(6)=4$.  So $(12+6)^{8}= 0$ but $o(18) \ne 8$; $o(18) = 4$.  On the other hand,  if $o(8)=3$ and $o(6)= 4$ and the $o(14) = 12$.

Comment: It's clear (although you'll have to prove it) that if $g^k = 1$ then $o(g)|k$.  So if $o(g) = m$ and $o(h)=n$ then $o(gh)|mn$.  It'll take a bit of finagling to show $o(gh) = mn/gcd(mn)$ in fact...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $gh=hg$, we have $(gh)^k= g^k h^k$.

Thus, if $(gh)^k=1$, then $g^k = h^{-k} \in \langle g \rangle \cap \langle h \rangle = 1$ because $\gcd(m,n)=1$.

Therefore, $k$ is a multiple of both $m$ and $n$.

I hope you can finish now.

Comment: @IHF Why is <g> intersect <h> = 1? Can you expand on that?

Comment: @JamesDickens, if $x \in \langle g \rangle \cap \langle h \rangle$ then $o(x)$ divides both $m$ and $n$.

Comment: @IHF Do you not mean that m , n divide o(x)?

Comment: @JamesDickens, no, I meant what I said because the order of an element  divides the order of the group.