# Order of abelian groups and multiples of elements

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to solve the following problem:

If $G$ is a group and $g,h \in G$ such that $gh = hg$. Assume $O(g) = m$  and $O(h) = n $ where $\gcd(m,n) = 1$. Prove that $O(gh) = mn$.

I have reasoned that $g$ and $h$ cannot be inverses since their order is different, and I suspect the answer is that the $O(gh)$ should therefore be equal to the $\mathrm{LCM}(m,n) = mn$. But I'm not sure how to show this is the lowest possible order. Perhaps a proof by contradiction? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1701927/let-g-be-a-group-and-g-h-in-g-such-that-gh-hg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the map
$$
f\colon\mathbb{Z}\to G,
\quad
f(a)=(gh)^a
$$
Obviously $f$ is a group homomorphism and its image is $\langle gh\rangle$, whose order is exactly $O(gh)$. If $a\in\ker f$, we have $g^a=h^{-a}$. Then
$$
1=(g^m)^a=(g^a)^m=(h^{-a})^m=h^{-am}
$$
so $n\mid am$ and, since $\gcd(m,n)=1$ we conclude $n\mid a$. Therefore $h^{-a}=1$ and also $g^a=1$, so $m\mid a$. Thus $mn\mid a$ and so
$$
\ker f\subseteq mn\mathbb{Z}
$$
The other inclusion is obvious. Thus
$$
\langle gh\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}/mn\mathbb{Z}
$$
has $mn$ elements.

Comment: What does that last line mean? I don't understand Z/mnZ

Comment: @JamesDickens It's the quotient group